# Rails / Rack / Config.ru

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, webrick

Trying to follow the "Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial" and running `rails s`, getting the following error:

```
[path]\config.ru:1 in 'require': no such file to load -- fake_app
```

I've got the location of `fake_app.rb` in the PATH (which I presume is what rails/rack is trying to find)

Contents of `config.ru` are the default generated:

```
require "fake_app"

run Rack::Test::FakeApp
```

I am running rails 3.0.8 and Windows 7

Thanks for helping this complete novice out!

Comment: You might try replacing your `require` line with `require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)` and see if that works better? If that gets rid of your line 1 error, you might need to replace line 2 with `Run FakeApp::Application`

Comment: BTW, my answer was well in the way of a "novice answer" -- I am no expert in the proper structure of the `config.ru` file, I just looked at my old Rails 3 Tutorial project directory and found that's how it was configured :-)

Answer (score 2):

Did you generate this with `rails new [appname]` command? A default Rails 3.0 `config.ru` file should look more like this:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
run ApplicationName::Application
```

If all you've done at this point is install Ruby and Rails, I'd re-run the generator to get something that works.

Also, since you're on Windows, I wanted to recommend [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/) for your environment installation and setup. It mitigates a lot of the startup pain.

This is probably the tutorial you are speaking of, but I also highly recommend [Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) for a solid introduction to Rails 3. The [section about generating your first application](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec%3athe_first_application) may be handy in this situation.

Comment: Yes, the config.ru was generated with rails new [appname] .  Not sure why I'm not getting the standard default.  Also, yes, its the Hartl tutorial I'm following.  Will try the Rails Installer.

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but if the app name is demo_app and I run:       rails new demo_app    how should I expect config.ru to read?

Comment: The same `require` line as listed in my answer, with the last line being `run DemoApp::Application`.

Comment: Still did not work under Windows native for some reason.  Although your answers are exactly right.  Finally ended up going with Cygwin and running rails there.  Problem resolved.  Thanks